# How can I correct my Collatz Conjecture code?

Tags: python, collatz

I want to take the last number and multiply with the multiplier and add the increment. And put that number back into the list. I do not know how to put `s` into the list. As you can see it is "...8, 4, 2, 1], 4)" I want to put the 4 into the list.

```
def sfcollatz(n,divs=[2],mult=3,inc=1,maxSize=-1):
    result = []
    while n not in result and len(result)!=maxSize:
        result.append(n)
        d = next((d for d in divs if n%d==0),None)
        n =  (n*mult+inc) if not d else n//d
        s = mult*result[-1]+inc
        
    return result + ['...']*(n not in result),s

print(sfcollatz(27,[2],3,1,maxSize=200))
```

```
([27, 82, 41, 124, 62, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, 107, 322, 161, 484, 242, 121, 364, 182, 91, 274, 137, 412, 206, 103, 310, 155, 466, 233, 700, 350, 175, 526, 263, 790, 395, 1186, 593, 1780, 890, 445, 1336, 668, 334, 167, 502, 251, 754, 377, 1132, 566, 283, 850, 425, 1276, 638, 319, 958, 479, 1438, 719, 2158, 1079, 3238, 1619, 4858, 2429, 7288, 3644, 1822, 911, 2734, 1367, 4102, 2051, 6154, 3077, 9232, 4616, 2308, 1154, 577, 1732, 866, 433, 1300, 650, 325, 976, 488, 244, 122, 61, 184, 92, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1], 4)
```

Comment: @Darth-CodeX I think it is? If odd, do *3*1, otherwise divide by 2

Comment: What makes it more difficult for you to put `s` in the list than to put `n` in the list?

Comment: `return result + [...]*(n not in result) + [s]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "adding 4 into your array". Do you just mean you want it to go "...8, 4, 2, 1, 4]"? If so, you can just use the `.append()` function again. You also do not need to keep defining `s` in your while loop since it will always just take the final value:

```
def sfcollatz(n,divs,mult,inc,maxSize):
    result = []
    while n not in result and len(result)!=maxSize:
        result.append(n)
        d = next((d for d in divs if n%d==0),None)
        n =  (n*mult+inc) if not d else n//d
    s = mult*result[-1]+inc
    result.append(s)
    return result
```

Your question was a little vague, but I hope this answers it. Let me know if you need any further help or clarification :)

Comment: I didn't understand why removing default arguments solves any problem.

Comment: OP said in comments he wants to be able to use different multipliers and divisors? Not exactly sure..

Comment: With or without default arguments, they can pass any arguments they want when calling the function in either case.

Comment: Yeah I just edited my answer after realizing sorry